# Django template tag show value not key

Tags: django, django-views, django-template-filters, django-widget, choicefield

This is probably a simple answer, but I can't seem to find it in the docs.

How do I display the value of a choice field in template tags? Using **.value** did not work as I thought it may.

Right now it's just displaying the **Key**:

```
user_update
```

when I call this **template tag** on my **html**:

```
{{ ticket.current_status }}
```

from my **forms.py**:

```
current_status = ChoiceField(
    label = "",
    choices = STATUS_CHOICES,
    widget = Select(attrs={
        'class': 'h-10 flex flex-row justify-items-left',
    })
)
```

and my **views.py**:

```
class StaffSupportTicketUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StaffSupportTicketUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search'] = SearchForm()
        context['ticket'] = self.get_object()
        return context
```

and my **models.py**:

```
class SupportTicketModel(Model):
    ...

    current_status = CharField(default='new_ticket', choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=35)

    ...
```

finally, my **STATUS_CHOICES**

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
('new_ticket', 'New ticket submitted'),
('user_update', 'User updated ticket'),
('need_info', "Need more information"),
('completed', 'Completed'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method that is dynamically created for your field because it has choices, it will return the human readable value of the field

```
{{ ticket.get_current_status_display }}
```

Comment: @Iaian Shelvington I would have never guessed this one. Works like a charm.